# SQLite - Excluding rows from a query based on certain column values, without using correlated subqueries

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm working with the `classicmodels` database, originally for MySQL, but which we're using with SQLite. Within this database, there are 2 tables of interest, the `orderdetails` table...

```sql
CREATE TABLE `orderdetails` (
  `orderNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `productCode` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `quantityOrdered` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `priceEach` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `orderLineNumber` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`orderNumber`,`productCode`)
);
```

... and the `products` table.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `productCode` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `productName` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
  `productLine` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `productScale` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `productVendor` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `productDescription` text NOT NULL,
  `quantityInStock` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `buyPrice` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `MSRP` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`productCode`)
);
```

I've written a query to list all the distinct order numbers, along with the product lines of the products within their orders. Here is the query, with the first few rows of the corresponding output.

```sql
sqlite> SELECT DISTINCT orderdetails.orderNumber, products.productLine
> FROM orderdetails JOIN products
> ON orderdetails.productCode == products.productCode;
```

```
orderNumber  productLine 
-----------  ------------
10100        Vintage Cars
10101        Vintage Cars
10102        Vintage Cars
10103        Classic Cars
10103        Trucks and B
10103        Vintage Cars
10104        Classic Cars
10104        Trucks and B
10104        Trains      
10105        Classic Cars
10105        Vintage Cars
10105        Trains      
10105        Ships       
10106        Planes      
10106        Ships       
10106        Vintage Cars
10107        Motorcycles
```

Now, **I want to exclude all rows which contain order numbers corresponding to orders which contain Planes**. For example, in the output above, order number 10106 contains products that are either Planes or Ships - since 10106 represents an order which contains planes (among other things), BOTH of these rows should be removed in such a query.

A simple subquery approach yields the right answer...

```sql
SELECT orderNumber FROM orders EXCEPT
SELECT DISTINCT orderdetails.orderNumber FROM orderdetails JOIN products
ON orderdetails.productCode == products.productCode
WHERE products.productLine == "Planes";
```

... however the catch here, is that **I can't use correlated subqueries** - the question that I am trying to tackle has explicitly stated that these subqueries are not allowed.

**What have I tried?**

A simple exclusion clause (such as `WHERE products.productLine != "Planes"`) won't do the trick, as this only removes the order numbers of orders which ONLY contain planes. If an order contains planes **and** ships (for example), that number will remain in the query - not good!

My initial research into similar questions on StackOverflow seems only to bring up answers suggesting the use of subqueries (which would be awesome in other situations, but unfortunately not in this problem - we're avoiding subqueries).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say "the catch here is that I can't use correlated subqueries". But the query that you say yields the right answer, namely...

```
SELECT orderNumber FROM orders EXCEPT
SELECT DISTINCT orderdetails.orderNumber FROM orderdetails JOIN products
ON orderdetails.productCode == products.productCode
WHERE products.productLine == "Planes";
```

... does not, in fact, contain a correlated subquery. In fact it doesn't contain a subquery at all, if you're going by the true definition of what a subquery is. So if the restriction really is "don't use subqueries", then the above query actually abides by the restriction, and is fine.

Comment: This is an interesting take! Would you be able to briefly elaborate on what the difference is between the inner `SELECT` statement I've used here, and the inner `SELECT` statement that would be used in a subquery? From my naive understanding, any inner `SELECT` statement constitutes a subquery, but this answer topples that on its head.

Comment: Sure! A subquery would be a SELECT statement that is enclosed in parentheses; it is in turn part of a larger query, and if you removed the subquery then the overall query would not run. Sometimes the subquery actually makes reference to attributes from the enclosing query; this subquery would be a "correlated subquery". Your EXCEPT query, on the other hand, involves two queries both of which are on an equal footing. If you got rid of the "EXCEPT" keyword and one of the two queries, the remainder would run just fine.

Comment: Another point to make here is that what you refer to in your comment as an "inner" SELECT statement is not in fact "inner" at all. It is simply a second statement that comes after the first, with an "EXCEPT" in between the two.

Comment: Likewise the query I've given above is not a correlated subquery which "is a SELECT statement nested inside another T-SQL statement, which contains a reference to one or more columns in the outer query. The correlated subquery can be said to be dependent on the outer query. ...A plain subquery is not dependent on the outer query, can be run independently of the outer query, and will return a result set"(https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3485291/Using-a-Correlated-Subquery-in-a-T-SQL-Statement.htm)

Comment: @Nabav, great explanations!  Cheers.

Comment: Thanks @user9601310! You are right, your solution is fine too, and meets the requirement of avoiding a correlated subquery (it uses a plain-vanilla subquery, as opposed to a correlated subquery).

Answer (score 1):

But you could do something like this, right?

```
SELECT DISTINCT orderNumber FROM orders 
WHERE ordernumber NOT IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT orderdetails.orderNumber FROM orderdetails 
JOIN products ON orderdetails.productCode == products.productCode
WHERE products.productLine == "Planes"
);
```

Comment: Unfortunately not, sorry :( Your query still contains a correlated subquery (`SELECT DISTINCT orderdetails.orderNumber ...
WHERE products.productLine == "Planes"`) . I need to avoid using subqueries altogether!

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation, if you just want the `orderNumber` (which your sample code suggests is what you want):

```
SELECT od.orderNumber
FROM orderdetails od JOIN
     products p
     ON od.productCode = p.productCode
GROUP BY od.orderNumber
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN p.productLine = 'Planes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;  -- none of those
```